# In fortify audit workbench tool what do u mean by filter set

Tags: fortify

In fortify audit workbench tool we have different type of filter set say 
1.security auditor view
2.developer view
3.critical exposure
4.hotspot etc
 what are those filter set and what are the difference between each filter set..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the default filter sets that are delivered with the product. They can be modified to fit your needs. I only use the Security Auditor View because it shows all issues and lets me decide what I should remediate.

Default filter descriptions:
 - **Security Auditor View**: Issues with the most comprehensive set
   of rules. (Shows all results)
 - **Developer View**: Issues include a balance between producing
   results that detail all potential issues and a targeted set of
   possible vulnerabilities.
 - **Critical Exposure**: Issues within categories that have been
   proven to be high priority issues across multiple industries and
   within a variety of environments. (Only the big-baddies)
 - **Hotspot**: Issues that are particularly interesting to developers, such
   as high accuracy bugs.

If you turn on the Filter tab (Options->Show View->Filters) you will be able to see how these filters are defined.

Comment: Good answer. I think it is worth adding that in Audit Workbench, Tools->Project Configuration allows you to see and define the list of FilterSets.